# URL Hash w/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to rewrite a URL from something like this:

```
http://www.asdf.com/index.php
```

to

```
http://www.asdf.com/#welcome
http://www.asdf.com/#test
```

Right now, the welcome/test pages are sliders on the page and it moves it around without changing the url from index.php to welcome/test.  How can I directly link these sliders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an article on preserving bookmarkability and the back button with Ajax.

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/10/26/ajax-handling-bookmarks-and-back-button.html

Answer (score 0):

You would use a bit of JavaScript on the page to detect which (if any) sliders are in the URL and then triggering the action that exposes them.

Answer (score 0):

you can not modify what the user has put in the url, you want to make sure your links say that. The only way you can change the url is with a redirect. you would need to use something like .htaccess files on apache to rewrite the .php urls to 'seo friendly' urls.

browsers auto detect the parts after # and go to that part of the page (if it exists). It does not do anything for the server though.